# How to concatenate strings of multiple columns from table in SQL Server using dplyr?

Tags: sql-server, r, dplyr, string-concatenation, dbplyr

As title, I would like to concatenate a few columns from a table in SQL Server, I tried to use the `paste` function as below but give the following error:

```
> tbl(channel,'##iris') %>% 
+   mutate(string=paste(Species,'-',
+                       Sepal.Length,'-',
+                       Sepal.Width,'-',
+                       Petal.Length,'-',
+                       Petal.Width,sep=''))
Error: PASTE() is not available in this SQL variant
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution [here](https://beanumber.github.io/mysql-r-webinar/dplyr.html) provided by Ben Baumer., and want to share it here.

The approach is to use `CONCAT` instead of `paste`.

```
> tbl(channel,'##iris') %>% 
+   group_by(Species,Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width) %>%
+   summarise(string=MAX(CONCAT(Species,'-',
+                               Sepal.Length,'-',
+                               Sepal.Width,'-',
+                               Petal.Length,'-',
+                               Petal.Width))) %>%
+   head(.,1)
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 6]
# Database: Microsoft SQL Server 11.00.6251[dbo@WCDCHCMSAH01\CMSAH_DC7_MP1/data_ha_amr]
# Groups:   Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length
  Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width string              
  <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>               
1 setosa          4.30        3.00         1.10       0.100 setosa-4.3-3-1.1-0.1
```

Comment: Why are you using summarize and MAX ? concat alone seems to do what you need

Answer (score 2):

Using the `tidyverse` on R `data.frames`, `tidyr::unite` would be the idiomatic way to go.

Not being a `dplyr` verb though, it has not been translated to be used through `dbplyr` / `SQL`.

You can define your own `unite` this way in SQL server (I couldn't test unfortunately but it should work) :

```
unite.tbl <- function (data, col, ..., sep = "_", remove = TRUE) 
{
  dot_names <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)
  shown_cols <- if (remove) 
    setdiff(data$ops$vars, dot_names)
  else data$ops$vars
  shown_col_str <- paste(shown_cols, collapse = ", ")
  concat_str <- paste0("CONCAT(",paste(dot_names, collapse = paste0(",'",sep,"',")),")")
  col <- deparse(substitute(col))
  subquery <- capture.output(show_query(data), type = "message")[-1] %>% paste(collapse = " ")
  query    <- paste("SELECT",shown_col_str,",",concat_str,"AS",col,"FROM (",subquery,")")
  tbl(data$src$con, sql(query))
}
```

and then :

```
tbl(channel,'##iris') %>%
  unite(string,
        Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width,
        sep = '',remove=FALSE)
```

For a DBMS that supports the `||` concatenation operator (e.g. `Oracle`), just replace the `concat_str` definition by :

```
concat_str <- paste(dot_names, collapse = paste0(" || '", sep, "' || "))
```

Comment: This should be the answer, and dbplyr should adopt this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a couple of small modifications to @moodymudskipper's solution to get it to work. This was using Oracle.

```
unite.tbl <- function (data, col, ..., sep = "_", remove = TRUE) 
{
  # remove the list call
  dot_names <- sapply(substitute(...)[-1], deparse)
  shown_cols <- if (remove) 
    # replace $ops$vars with colnames
    setdiff(data %>% colnames(), dot_names)
  else data %>% colnames()
  shown_col_str <- paste(shown_cols, collapse = ", ")
  concat_str <- paste(dot_names, collapse = paste0(" || '", sep, "' || "))
  col <- deparse(substitute(col))
  # remove type arg
  subquery <- capture.output(show_query(data))[-1] %>% paste(collapse = " ")
  query    <- paste(
    "SELECT", shown_col_str, ",",
    concat_str, "AS", col,
    "FROM (",
    subquery,
    ")"
  )
  tbl(data$src$con, sql(query))
}
```

What I need to add for my use case is a way for NA and/or NULL to be ignored, as the `na.rm` arg from `tidyr::unite` does.

EDIT: And here is the version with an na.rm argument. I did need the `list` wrapper around `...`. This may need adapted for other RDBMSs than Oracle.

```
unite.tbl <- function (data, col, ..., sep = "_", remove = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE) 
{
  dot_names <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)
  shown_cols <- data %>% colnames()
  shown_cols <- `if`(
    remove,
    setdiff(shown_cols, dot_names),
    shown_cols
  )
  shown_col_str <- paste(shown_cols, collapse = ", ")
  concat_str <- ifelse(
    na.rm,
    paste0(
      paste0(
        "NVL2(",
        dot_names%>% head(-1), ", ",
        dot_names%>% head(-1), " || '", sep, "'", 
        ", '')", 
        collapse = " || "
      ),
      " || NVL(", dot_names%>% tail(1), ", '')"
    ),
    paste0(dot_names, collapse = paste0(" || '", sep, "' || "))
  )
  col <- deparse(substitute(col))
  subquery <- capture.output(show_query(data))[-1] %>% paste(collapse = " ")
  query    <- paste(
    "SELECT", shown_col_str, ",",
    concat_str, "AS", col,
    "FROM (",
    subquery,
    ")"
  )
  tbl(data$src$con, sql(query))
}
```